# Determine orientation of an L shape

Tags: geometry

Having coordinates of an L shape vertices (vectors in Cartesian coordinate system), in no particular order, what is the easiest way to determine the orientation of said L shape, i.e. which one it is from the ones you can see in the attached picture (you can assume it is always aligned with coordinate system axes and in 2 dimensions).

[image: L shapes]

Comment: What’s wrong with simply comparing coordinates?

Comment: You mean that this L-shape has one of the 4 given positions, thus never in a slant position ? Furthermore, do the horizontal and vertical lengths and the width are variable ? In this case, you have to consider the skeletons of the shapes (otherwise the remark of @amd is justified).